# How to add multiple proxies in React's package.json?

Tags: reactjs

I have already one proxy added in my React project. Now I need to add more proxies in order to run project efficiently. As the thing is, when we add any URL in proxy doesn't give CORS error. So this is what my intention is.

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "proxy": "URL1....", /* <-- URL added and I want to add more URLs in proxy */
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",....
}
```

What could be the best solution to add multiple proxies?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can't..

I use the package 'http-proxy-middleware' for this purpose. Works very well.

Link: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

You can even proxy to different sites completely. Example:

```
app.use(
   '/api',
   createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
      changeOrigin: true
   })
);
```

Comment: CORS is a different error to proxy problems. CORS doesnt allow certain addresses to access the server. This must be fixed on the API to allow CORS

Comment: This is for development only, right?

Comment: That is what I use it for in this case. I am sure it can have its uses in some test or production scenarios as well though.